# What does this symbol mean

Tags: real, symbols

This is a real life question.

I have a hat that has this symbol on it

[image]
I can't figure out what it means.
I have asked everyone I know. But I didn't get good answers.

So What does it mean?
Even if you don't know for sure. I would love your thoughts.

P.S. If this is the wrong place to ask this question please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says:

> DUNK. The letters are just rotated around.

It looks like this:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the incite. Just wondering have you ever seen this symbol before?

Comment: No I have not, I was just playing around with the logo in paint and realized the letters were rotated!